# Spring RestTemplate how to use POJO with application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

When I try to use POJO with MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED

```
    ExampleRequest exampleRequest = exampleRequest();
    exampleRequest.setId("id");
    exampleRequest.setName("name");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpEntity<ExampleRequest> exampleRequestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(exampleRequest, headers);

    restTemplate.postForObject(url, exampleRequestEntity, String.class)
```

I get:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for [ExampleRequest] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
```

Is there any way to use POJO with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `MultiValueMap<String, String> map`?

Comment: Just passing  the `FormHttpMessageConverter` to the `RestTemplate` constructor will do the trick (e.g. `new RestTemplate(List.of(new FormHttpMessageConverter()))`).

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Which type of List class to use?

Answer (score 2):

`FormHttpMessageConverter` might be missing. Have you tried adding it manually?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application","x-www-form-urlencoded", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(mediaType));
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

(Relevant for spring boot)

Answer (score 0):

There is possible to use the [`FormHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) which is able to convert data to/from a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` required for the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type. Add the following configuration to the class implementing [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html).

```
@Bean
public FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter() {

    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter= new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(mediaType));
    return formHttpMessageConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
     converters.add(formHttpMessageConverter());
     super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```